# If $w(x)=h(g(m(x)))$, find $w'(2)$, given values of $m$, $g$, $h$ and their derivatives

Tags: calculus

> Let $w(x)=h(g(m(x)))$. Find $w'(2)$ where $m(2)=3$, $m'(2)=4$, $g'(4)=7$, $g(3)=1$, $g'(3)=1$, $g(4)=0$, $h'(1)=2$, and $h'(7)=-2$.

The composite function is given, but it is barely complex to solve this. Can anybody help? Where is the trick?

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Chain rule says that if $h(x) = f(g(x))$ then $h'(x) = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$.

So if $w(x) = h(g(m(x)))$ then $w'(x) = h'((g(m(x)))\cdot [g(m(x))]'$.

If you apply the chain rule again to figure out what $[g(m(x))]'$ you get an explicit formula for $w'(x)$.

> $w'(x) = h'(g(m(x)))[g(m(x))]'=h'(g(m(x)))\cdot g'(m(x))\cdot m'(x)$

So just plug in the values.

> $w'(2)=h'(g(m(2)))\cdot g'(m(2))\cdot m'(2) $